# Bounding functions involving integrals (PDEs by Walter Strauss)

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Multiple times in Partial Differential Equations by Walter Strauss, e.g. in Ch 3.4 and 3.5, the author bounds the absolute value of a function involving integrals by using the maximum of the absolute value of the functions being integrated. For example they bound the following function:

$u(x,t)=\frac{1}{2}[\phi(x+ct)+\phi(x-ct)]+\frac{1}{2c}\int_{x-ct}^{x+ct}\psi+\frac{1}{2c}\int\int_{\Delta}f$

By

$|u(x,t)|\le max|\phi|+\frac{1}{2c}\cdot max|\psi|\cdot 2ct+\frac{1}{2c} \cdot max|f| \cdot ct^2$

What allows them to do this?

It seems like they multiply the area of the region being integrated over by the maximum value of the absolute value of the function.

They do a similar thing in Ch 3.5 and mention the inequality is related to the maximum principle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a bounded area $\Omega$ and a continuous function $f$:
\begin{align*}
\left |\int_{\Omega} f(x) dx\right| &\leq \int_{\Omega} |f(x)| dx \\
&\leq \max_{\overline{\Omega}} |f| \int_{\Omega} dx\\
&=\left(\max_{\overline{\Omega}} |f|\right)  |\Omega|,
\end{align*}
where $|\Omega|$ denotes the (Lebesgue) measure of $\Omega$.

Comment: Thanks. I think its quite intuitive because $f(x)$ may be negative in which case the area under $|f(x)|$ will be larger than the integral of $f(x)$. And the second step makes sense because $max|f| \int dx$ is like the area of a rectangle of height $max |f|$ over $\Omega$ which will be larger than the area under $|f(x)|$ over $\Omega$.

Comment: Yes, these are basic properties of the integral.